# Can I use a URL with CFZIP action=read?

Tags: coldfusion-10, railo

When I use Coldfusion 10, locally, I can read a zip file's text file content using:

```
<cfzip action="read" file="http://someurl.com/somezip.zip" entrypath="sometext.txt" variable="somevar"  />
```

But on my Railo VPS, this produces an internal server error 500 on IIS7.5

Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong with Railo?

Comment: Help for 500 errors: Open IIS > Click on site > Open "Error Pages" > On right side, click "Edit Feature Settings" > change to "Detailed errors" > Click OK.  Then rerun your page to see the actual error.  When you are done, reset this back to "Detailed errors for local requests...".  You could search the CF logs as well.  I find that toggling this setting is quicker for me.

Comment: @Scott Jibben thanks for the advice. I will change the IIS setting & rerun the page. Then, I will have a look at the error log, because the error displayed on the webpage was so vague & unspecific. And interestingly was not a Coldfusion error...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about Railo, but [according to the `<cfzip>` doc](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-u-z/cfzip.html), ACF does not support reading off `http://`, only `ram://`.  You should use `<cfhttp>` to download the content first.

Comment: Thanks @Henry for this, but I was pleasantly surprised by this behaviour. With Coldfusion 10, you can indeed use a URL successfully. I don't know whether this is a bug that is actually advantageous. I have tested this many times, successfully. I am just not sure why Railo does not accept a URL?

Comment: @CharlesRobertson once again it's because CF doc is often wrong and they have recently killed off the comment section.  Urgh!

Comment: this behaviour was a real surprise. I always thought that ACF cfzip read, only accepted a system path. I am pretty sure, not even Adobe know about this. Some kind of Easter egg maybe?

Comment: @CharlesRobertson - Notice url's work with cffile as well? Not sure it is a great idea for cffile, but very interesting...

Comment: @Leigh the problem is that Railo does not seem to comply with the URL value, unlike ACF.

Comment: @CharlesRobertson - That makes sense. Different implementation, different features.  Honestly, I have never seen the feature "promoted" in the ACF docs either, so it may just be a happy side effect of the implementation.  However, you can still achieve the same end in Railo obviously. Albeit, with an extra step or two.

Comment: I thought of using CFHTTP, but then it gets a little messy, because I would need to download it and then remove it etc? Is there a cleaner way with Railo?

Comment: @CharlesRobertson - Unless Railo supports reading a zip from binary (I do not think so), that probably is the cleanest way.